# Web framework for look & feel of mobile platform

Tags: android, ios, look-and-feel

Is there any good web framework which is cross-platform and provides me with the look & feel of the mobile platform which accesses the website, specifically iOS and Android.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Sencha Touch http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/